# Cleaning an R&T toilet fill valve

Tags: plumbing, toilet, valve

I have a toilet with an R&T fill valve, unknown model. The top of the fill valve is leaking out spurts of water making a hissing sound. I'd like to clean it by opening it.

So far I was able to remove the top blue cap and horizontal pin. The difficult parts trying to remove this white cap with the two parallel lines. I used this previous [DIY stack exchange post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/71960/cleaning-an-rt-a1250-toilet-fill-valve)'s instructions:

> Take a pair of standard (not needlenose) pliers and grip the two raised walls that contained the adjustment arm, push down into the shaft and turn. This unlocks the top of the mechanism so you can just remove it.

When I rotate this white cap counter-clockwise, the whole valve rotates with the cap. The cap does not loosen. Not sure what else to try. Anyone familiar with this?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: I have one that's similar, I press down (like a pill bottle) and rotate counter-clockwise.   I wonder if the bottom of your toilet is now leaking if the shaft is spinning too.

Comment: It may be that it just needs a lot of force? The bottom part is not leaking which is good.